# changing the reticle if an object is intractable

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im a beginner in Unity and im actually making a horror game,I recently added reticle into my game.
I want to change the reticle if u can interact w an object (im using raycasts).
Can someone check my code pls?

```
public Camera mainCam;
public LayerMask interactableLayerMask;
UnityEvent onInteract;
[SerializeField] GameObject reticle;
[SerializeField] GameObject interactReticle;


void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(mainCam.transform.position, mainCam.transform.forward, out hit, 2, interactableLayerMask))
    {
        if (hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>() != false)
        {
            onInteract = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>().onInteract;
            interactReticle.SetActive(true);
            reticle.SetActive(false);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                onInteract.Invoke();
            }
        }
        if (hit.collider == null)
        {
             interactReticle.SetActive(false);
             reticle.SetActive(true);            }
    }
}
```

Comment: A raycast is pretty pixel perfect. So if you have a small key it will need to be very accurately over it to notice.  But other than that whsts wrong with the code?

Comment: @BugFinder it doesn't work. the reticle after it goes on the object  stays the same (it changes but doesn't get the normal one back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not rely on `if (hit.collider == null)`. `Physics.Raycast` returns a `bool` to indicate if it hit something, see [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

> bool Returns true if the ray intersects with a Collider, otherwise false.

Try something like this:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(...) {
    // your code for interaction
}
else {
    interactReticle.SetActive(false);
    reticle.SetActive(true); 
}
```

This could be then further optimised with a flag like `hasInteractiveFocus` to not set the active state of the game objects all the time.